# what word means "to be exposed to new things"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

I need a word other than exposure to explain that the benefit of a college education has lead to "exposure" to different cultures.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, _exposure_ to cultures sounds all right. Although I wouldn't think the benefit lead to exposure, but rather _a benefit of college education is exposure_.

Comment: Do you really mean " has lead(sic) to"? Or do you mean "is that it leads to..," or "is that it entails (or includes)..,"

Answer (score 2):

"knowledge", "familiarity", "introduction"

Answer (score 1):

would it be:

1.*discovering* different cultures.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discover

2.*revealing*  different cultures.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reveal

Answer (score 0):

It would be sensible to say:

> the benefit of a college education has led to **acquaintance with**
>   different cultures

Given the following definition of **[acquaint](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acquaint)**:

> To furnish or give experimental
>   knowledge of; to make (one) to know; to make familiar.

Answer (score 0):

A college education has lead to ***an appreciation of*** different cultures.

or

A college education has lead to ***a cross-pollination with*** different cultures.

Comment: I think "cross-pollination" stands out like a neon shirt. It might be overdoing it.